# Index error when using MongoEngine 'unique_with' : index already exists with different options

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am using MongoEngine and I have declared two related classes:

```py
from mongoengine import StringField, DynamicDocument, BooleanField


class BaseFile(DynamicDocument):
    name = StringField(unique_with=["category"])
    category = StringField()
    active = BooleanField()

    meta = {
        "indexes": [
            "active"
        ],
        "allow_inheritance": True,
    }


class SpecialFile(BaseFile):
    tag = StringField()
```

When querying one of those classes I get the following error:

`OperationFailure: Index with name: name_1_category_1 already exists with different options`

However, I have not created that Index before, and it is declared only once (in the `unique_with`). How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known open issue](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/629) with mongoengine: you are going to get those index errors when using `unique_with` in combination with inheritance. Mongoengine tries to create the index twice, and the error happens.

However there is a workaround (showed in the linked github issue): declare the uniqueness inside the `meta` dictionary, with the index declaration.

```
from mongoengine import StringField, DynamicDocument, BooleanField


class BaseFile(DynamicDocument):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    category = StringField(required=True)
    active = BooleanField()

    meta = {
        "indexes": [
            "active",
            {"fields": ["name", "category"], "unique": True},
        ],
        "allow_inheritance": True,
    }


class SpecialFile(BaseFile):
    tag = StringField()
```